# Return URL is cleared after entering incorrect password

Tags: bug, login

When I click "log in", a parameter thing of the page I was on before logging is passed through the URL to the login page (sorry if I am using incorrect terminology; I'm not a web developer):

[image]

This takes me to the original page properly:

[image]

However, if I enter an incorrect password, the `returnurl` is removed:

[image]

If I then type in the correct password, I am returned to the homepage instead of the page I was on before:

[image]

---

**Workaround:**

Every time you type in the wrong password, hit the "back" button in your browser.

Comment: That's the punishment for typing wrong password. ;-)

Comment: @ShadowWizard My password is pretty long, so I often make a mistake while typing it :)

Comment: yup, guess you're neither the first nor the last who "suffer" from such problems. ;)